# ImageButton Action don't work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I have made some Imagebuttons in Absolute layout and then rotate the whole layout with all it's buttons and now I have a problem that the action of the imagebuttons not work probably as the action is not rotated with the imagebutton

please if anyone knows what's going on let me know

the main.xml

```
<AbsoluteLayout
  android:id="@+id/wheelLayout"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_x="-250px" android:clickable="true">


    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/wheelBG"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/wheel"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/accounts"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="258dp"
        android:layout_y="222dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="accountsOnClick"
        android:src="@drawable/accounts"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cards"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="228dp"
        android:layout_y="291dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="cardsOnClick"
        android:src="@drawable/cards"/>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Then I have made a function to rotate the whole absolute layout using RotateAnimation and to angle in a specific duration

and I have defined the action of the buttons

public void accountsOnClick(View view) {
        System.out.println("imageButton1OnClick");
    }

Before rotation the action is working well but after rotation the action is not working

Comment: well, there's something strange in your code, isn't it?

Comment: FYI, AbsoluteLayout is **deprecated**

Comment: I know that it is deprecated, I'm working on 2.1 platform and I really need to position Imagebuttons in a circular order to fit my design, so I didn't find any other layout that can let me set x, y of item except absolute layout, If you have any other idea that may help I will be thankful

Answer (score 0):

You should used two different layouts. One before start animation and second special layout which you can use after animation finished. Use [AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) to handle animation finished event. Then inflate a new layout which will be looks like to already rotated layout.

Comment: This solution will not work in my case as the animation happen randomly with different angles and I can't handle all angles and make different layout for each angle

Comment: Other way. You can use View.OnTouchListener with parent view or a whole activity. Then you can listen touch event and calculate a borders of GUI elements manually. It's too hard and needs a lot ugly manual work.